# Function of /etc/cron.hourly

Tags: command-line, scripts, bash, cron-jobs

If I create a script and then place it in this folder (/etc/cron.hourly), will my system run this script hourly? Or does my script need to begin with a command as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yep, you got it.

Just start it with a `#!/bin/bash` like you normally would. And make sure you `sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/yourscript` because it won't run without execute permissions.

Answer (score 31):

Every script placed in folder `/etc/cron.hourly` would run on hourly basis.

However your files needs to be:

- executable,
- match the Debian cron script namespace `(^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$)`.

So for example **if you've script with extension, it won't work**.

To print the names of the scripts which would be invoked, run:

```
sudo run-parts --report --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

Comment: Is there any reasonable explanation why file name extensions are considered bad in that context...?

Answer (score 8):

Anything in `/etc/cron.hourly` will be executed hourly, just like anything in `/etc/cron.daily` will be run once a day.

Make sure the file is executable, and start it with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/python` (or `#!/usr/bin/env python`) or whatever is appropriate for the type of script you'll be running.