# How do I run a Supervisor task from cron.hourly?

Tags: cron, anacron, supervisor

I have a task defined in [Supervisor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/supervisor) that I would like to invoke hourly from `/etc/cron.hourly`. I can run it manually, but not from `run-parts`:

`$ sudo supervisorctl start my-task` -- works

`# . /etc/cron.hourly/my-script` -- works

`$ sudo run-parts --report --test /etc/cron.hourly` -- lists `my-script` as expected

`$ sudo run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` -- fails with:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/my-script:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/cron.hourly/my-script: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/my-script exited with return code 1
```

The contents of `/etc/cron.hourly/my-script` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/supervisorctl start my-task
```

I have confirmed that:

- [permission, filename and shebang of `my-script` are correct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7676/function-of-etc-cron-hourly)
- [I am using the full path to `supervisorctl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35917302/236081)
- the cron script runs at [17 minutes past](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149490/what-is-the-story-behind-the-default-times-set-in-etc-crontab) -- at which point [`/var/log/syslog`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log) reads:

  ```
  (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
  Jun 14 10:17:01 DevAPps postfix/sendmail[16202]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
  ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why the link to ubuntuforums? Are you saying that you solved the problem, and it was a non-unix style line ending?

Comment: @Jos updated question, it was a problem, but sadly not the fix

Comment: Despite the wording `failed to exec /etc/cron.hourly/my-script: No such file or directory` I think your script *does* get executed. Is there anything useful in the Supervisor log? Can you add some more debugging to your script, like `echo $(date) >> /tmp/debugfile` or something?

Comment: @Jos in fact, my first fix fixed it, but I forgot to chmod; I've reverted the question for clarity -- but thanks for the comment, it got me thinking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created `my-script` on Windows, so the shebang was correct, but had a Windows line ending. [This will cause a cron script to fail.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2018840) Recreating the script on Ubuntu (and `chmodding` it etc) fixed the problem.